# Template error with dependent names

Tags: c++, templates

In the following code, I get a compile error that I don't have if I remove the templates :

```
template<int DIM> class myClass
{
public :
    enum Mode {aa,bb};
    myClass(){};
};

template<int DIM> class  myClass2
{
    myClass2(){};
    void myfunc(myClass::Mode m);
};

template<int DIM>
void myClass2<DIM>::myfunc(myClass<DIM>::Mode m)
{
}
```

> test.cpp(19) : warning C4346: 'myClass::Mode' : dependent name is not a type
>          prefix with 'typename' to indicate a type
>   test.cpp(19) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'm'

If I remove the  like:

```
template<int DIM>
void myClass2<DIM>::myfunc(myClass::Mode m)
```

I get :

> test.cpp(19) : error C2955: 'myClass' : use of class template requires template argument list

And if I put the definition of `myfunc` directly in the declaration of the class (which I would like to avoid), it works.

What should I do and why does this happen?

Thanks

Comment: It seems to me the warning rather clear: "prefix `myClass<DIM>::Mode` with `typename`".

Comment: Please, the next time you ask a question post the actual source code the contains the error, and not something just like it or some portion of it. See http://sscce.org for information about how & why to post a minimal, complete sample program.

Comment: @Caron: indeed, when you know about it, this seems pretty clear. But when you never had such a warning, and never saw a code which has to declare a typename with the typename keyword (I mean, except inside templates), this makes it sound like all the odd warnings with little sense.... :/  
@Rob: ok.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe that you have two problems in your code.  The first is in this declaration in `myClass2`:

```
void myfunc(myClass::Mode m);
```

Because `myClass` is a template, you need to specify what the template parameter is.  I assume that you probably meant to write

```
void myfunc(myClass<DIM>::Mode m);
```

However, due to a weird idiosyncrasy in C++, you would write this as

```
void myfunc(typename myClass<DIM>::Mode m);
```

The `typename` keyword here tells C++ that `Mode` is the name of a type nested inside of the class `myClass<DIM>`.

Similarly, later in the code, the code

```
template<int DIM>
void myClass2<DIM>::myfunc(myClass<DIM>::Mode m)
{
}
```

should read

```
template<int DIM>
void myClass2<DIM>::myfunc(typename myClass<DIM>::Mode m)
{
}
```

to tell the compiler that `Mode` is the name of a type.

Hope this helps!

Comment: yeah ! thanks all, I was missing the typename ! I didn't know we had to add that since Mode is obviously a type....! The first problem was just a typo :p  Thanks, it works now :)  (4 minutes left to validate)

Answer (score 1):

Here you go...

```
template<int DIM> class myClass
{
public :
    enum Mode {aa,bb};
    myClass(){};
};

template<int DIM> class  myClass2
{
    myClass2(){};

    // you need to pass the template parameter to myClass
    // "typename" needs to be present when using types from templated classes
    // from within a templated class/function.
    void myfunc(typename myClass<DIM>::Mode m);
};

template<int DIM>
void myClass2<DIM>::myfunc(typename myClass<DIM>::Mode m)
{
}
```